# Mailchimp/Mandrill clients/wrappers generator

Tags: code-generation, mailchimp, mandrill

Does any one know how Mailchimp generates the api clients/wrappers for so many languages? Php, python, ruby, etc.

https://bitbucket.org/mailchimp/

Is there any opensource tool to help with that?

Comment: They certainly coded these wrappers themselves one by one.

Comment: In some of the repos they say: "Please note that we generate this client/wrapper, so while we're happy to look at any pull requests, ultimately we can't technically accept them...".That was what made me ask the question.